# Selecting elements from the DOM - Reasonml/BuckleScript querySelector

Tags: dom, reason, bucklescript

How would you select items from the DOM using Reason. I'm using bs-webapi for the DOM bindings here is what I want to do:

```
let parent = document |> Document.querySelector(".parent");
let child = Element.querySelector(".child", parent);
```

However, BuckleScript complains because parent isn't of the right type. It says parent is of type `option(Dom.element)` and parent is expected to be `Dom.element.t`. I'm new to Reason and trying to learn. I don't understand what `option(Dom.element)` means or how to make something like the above code block work. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unwrap the option variant, and we can do that with a switch and use the built-in None/Some variants.

You can find some documentation on the option variant here: https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/newcomer-examples.html#using-the-option-type

Here is some more documentation on option: https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/variant.html#option

To do this, you would change your code to something like this:

```
let parent = document |> Document.querySelector(".parent");
let child = switch (parent) {
  | Some(p) => switch (Element.querySelector(".child", p)) {
    | Some(c) => c
    | None => raise(Failure("Unable to find child selector"))
  }
  | None => raise(Failure("Unable to find parent selector"))
};
```

If you wanted to instead log to the console instead of fail, you would need to return a valid `Dom.element.t`, which could be something like this:

```
let emptyEl = document |> Document.createElement("noscript");
let parent = document |> Document.querySelector(".parent");
let child = switch (parent) {
  | Some(p) => switch (Element.querySelector(".child", p)) {
    | Some(c) => c
    | None => {
      Js.log("Unable to find child selector");
      emptyEl;
    }
  }
  | None => {
    Js.log("Unable to find parent selector");
    emptyEl;
  }
};
```

You would then want to check if your child element was a `noscript` to see if you found the child you were looking for.

Comment: This works. I was doing this; however, it was breaking because instead of raising a Failure I was trying to do a Js.log in the none. So types in the variant must match when using the option variant? How is a failure the same as Dom.element? Thank you for answering I'm just trying to get an understanding.

Comment: Yes, the types must still match. The reason `Js.log` didn't work is that it actually returns a `unit` type. Whereas the raise returns the type of `'a` which can be anything. So in the case above it would be a Dom.element.t.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply - that explains a lot. What if I didn't want want the program to break because I didn't find a parent? What if I just wanted to log that the parent wasn't found? I tried to but a Js.log below the switch and it didn't log because now I get an uncaught exception due to the Failure being raised.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show both methods and hopefully point you where you want to go.